# How to take full snapshot of a web page? (scrollable size large)

Tags: php, image-processing, snapshot, html-rendering

I want to take a snapshot of a web page. The image should show the full content of the browser window (without the scroll bar I mean).

I want to do this dynamically using a PHP script.

Comment: Why your question is tagged 'php'?

Comment: look at http://superuser.com/questions/39988/take-a-screen-shot-of-a-scrolling-window-that-includes-off-screen-parts

Comment: tagged php, because my requirement is to take snapshot of the pages dynamically using script

Comment: Sorry, but as I understand you, you want to take a screencap of a site, using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to invoke something like [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/). It does require an X server, but as indicated in the docs you can use Xvfb (a headless, virtual X server) to fill in that position. Try to recycle the same Xvfb instance each time though, to save resources.

There are also various web service providers offering services like this - eg, [webthumb](http://webthumb.bluga.net/home). This may be worth considering as well, depending on how much resources you have, and how much CutyCapt takes.